# Issue with SentOnBehalfOfName

Tags: outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin

i'm stack with *Outlook* issue where i want to change *Email Sender*. I want to send all emails from *Outlook* with one sender. When i change sender from Outlook it works fine but when i change it from *Outlook* *plugin* it's not work. I'm using following code:

```
private void adxOutlookEvents_ItemSend(object sender, ADXOlItemSendEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is MailItem)  
    {  
        MailItem mail = e.Item as MailItem;  
        mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "UserName";  
        mail.Save();  
        return; 
    } 
}
```

But nothing happens. I don't see any error or exception but email come to Outlook with old sender. Can you please help me with that?

UPDATED: The way how i fix it. We cant use property "SentOnBehalfOfName" Outlook handle it incorect. Except it you should use "Sender" property:

```
mail.Recipients.Add(mail.SentOnBehalfOfName);
mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
var adressEntry = mail.Recipients[mail.Recipients.Count].AddressEntry;
mail.Recipients.Remove(mail.Recipients.Count);
mail.Sender = adressEntry;
```

Comment: Please be aware that outlook is not displaying the change of the sender,  but does use it - very annoying.  Have you tried sending?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to add the temporary recipient - use Namespace.CreateRecipient, call Recipient.Resolve, then use its AddressEntry property.

Comment: Yeah but this is how i did it for now. Do you have any advise how to get AdressEntry better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending through Exchange and want to send on behalf of another user (do you have the permission?) or trying to send through a particular POP3/SMTP account (use MailItem.SendUsingAccount property)?

Comment: Yes i have rights for that i can change SendOnBefalf from Outlook. I'm sending email from Outlook and use Addin Express plugin for handle the events. How can i use SendUsingAccount? Can i change it from code how i can create this object for user email example@develop.local?

Comment: So what happens when you set SentOnBehalfOfName? What do you see in OutlookSpy (click IMessage) for the PR_SENDER_xyz and PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_xyz properties?

Comment: thank you for help i checked PR_SENDER and PR_SENT_REPRESENTING properties with OutlookSpy and discovered that  Outlook API for set SentOnBehalfName work incorect. But i found a wokreround how i can change SentObBehalfName. I can do if by setting Sender property. If somebody interesting on it you can see my code example in original post